# How to log actions to a database table in Django?

Tags: django

I'm making a Django application that incorporates users and movies. Users can "like" movies and I would like to have a database table that holds the relationships between users and the movies they liked.

I don't have a table of movies, just a table of users and each time a user likes a movie, I would like to create a record in a table like:

`uid = 10, mid = 325` (user with uid 10 likes movie with id 325)

etc.

Initially I thought I would create a model for the "Likes" but I am not entirely sure if that is the best approach for such a simple action. Is there a recommended standard for this type of activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to hold only the `id` of `movie`, and not an `FK` relationship to it, you can simply create a [`PickleField`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/), and store a list of the "likes" of the user in that field as a list or tuple. Everytime it changes, you can just updated this field of the `user` object.

If you later need access to the `Movie` objects, you can just query the database with the list of movie ids you have.

Another advantage of `PickleField` could be that you can store the data in the form:

```
((id, movie_name), (id, movie_name), ...)
```

That way, you dont have to query just for the movie name.

This is an alternative to the traditional foreignkey related tables;

Comment: Yes it's only the ID of a movie, but there could be a very large number of IDs associated with a user. Is PickleField recommended then too? Do you know the performance implications regarding i.e. 1000 users with 1000 movies each and a table with 1,000,000 rows to be searched?

Comment: well, there is a limit on everything. You cannot have 1M records, and expect the performance to be good, because what picklefield would do is, get everything in memory, and then process it. It is treated as a form field. It scales good for 1000 movies. if you read the documentation, https://github.com/shrubberysoft/django-picklefield They have an option of zipping the field that could save some space, but a memory hit.